# Ubuntu server does not connect to the internet anymore

Tags: ubuntu, internet, ethernet, ubuntu-14.04, ubuntu-server

I switched off my Ubuntu Server, but, when I started it, it didn't connect to the Internet. It is connected to the router via Ethernet. What can I do?

The result of `ipaddr` is:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN grup default
   link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
   inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
     valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
   inet6 ::1/128 scope host
     valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:40:f4:83:81:be brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: virbr0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default
    link/ether d2:76:9a:fb:1f:ea brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.x.x/x brd 192.168.x.x scope global birbr0
      valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

And, the result of `ifconfig` is:

```
lo            Link encap:Loopback locale
              indirizzo inet:127.0.0.1  Maschera:255.0.0.0
              indirizzo inet6: ::1/128 Scope:Host
              UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
              RX packets:5407 error:0dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
              TX packets:5407 error:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
              collisioni:0 txqueuelen:0
              Byte RX:374717 (374.7 KB)  Byte TX:374717 (374.7 KB)

virbr0        Link encap:Ethernet  IndirizzoHW d2:76:9a:fb:1f:ea
              indirizzo inet:192.168.x.x  Bcast:192.168.x.x  Maschera:255.255.255.0
              RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
              TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
              collisioni:0 txqueuelen:0
              Byte RX:0 (0.0 B)  Byte TX:0 (0.0 B)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should check whether your server received an IP-address. This can be checked via the command 'ip addr' on the console. This will yield something like:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d4:3d:7e:33:70:15 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.1/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::d63d:7eff:fe33:7015/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Look for your network interface card (NIC) name (in this case 'eth0') and look for the address behind 'inet'.

If you do have a valid IP-address, then check if you can ping a known host. For instance Ubuntu.org:

```
PING ubuntu.org (82.98.134.233) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from hl231.dinaserver.com (82.98.134.233): icmp_seq=1 ttl=50 time=51.2 ms
64 bytes from hl231.dinaserver.com (82.98.134.233): icmp_seq=2 ttl=50 time=39.6 ms
64 bytes from hl231.dinaserver.com (82.98.134.233): icmp_seq=3 ttl=50 time=31.9 ms
^C
--- ubuntu.org ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 3 received, 25% packet loss, time 3003ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 31.940/40.957/51.254/7.936 ms
```

At least then you know whether your connection to the internet is working. If not, try your connection to the router. Can you reach it? For instance in a browser:http://192.168.1.1 (replace with your router's IP). To determine your router's IP use 'route -n' command.

```
martin@jupiter:~$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0
```

The line starting with 0.0.0.0 is the one you need. The entry in the column 'Gateway' provides your router's IP.

To know for sure if your computer received an IP-address via DHCP check in the syslog. Using grep you'll see something like below. There is an entry 'DHCPACK' (DHCP Acknowledge) which tells you your server received an IP address via DHCP.

```
martin@jupiter:~$ cat /var/log/syslog | grep DHCP
Aug  4 08:48:53 jupiter NetworkManager[1131]: <info> Activation (eth0) Beginning DHCPv4 transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Aug  4 08:48:53 jupiter dhclient: Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.2.4
Aug  4 08:48:53 jupiter NetworkManager[1131]: <info> (eth0): DHCPv4 state changed nbi -> preinit
Aug  4 08:48:53 jupiter dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0xfe05734f)
Aug  4 08:48:53 jupiter dhclient: DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.123.100 on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x4f7305fe)
Aug  4 08:48:53 jupiter dhclient: DHCPOFFER of 192.168.123.100 from 192.168.123.253
Aug  4 08:48:53 jupiter dhclient: DHCPACK of 192.168.123.100 from 192.168.123.253
Aug  4 08:48:53 jupiter NetworkManager[1131]: <info> (eth0): DHCPv4 state changed preinit -> bound
Aug  4 08:48:54 jupiter dnsmasq[2723]: compile time options: IPv6 GNU-getopt DBus i18n IDN DHCP DHCPv6 no-Lua TFTP conntrack ipset auth
```

If all this is not working, then check your cabling and (hopeful) the lights on your NIC. Green lights should be visible indicating a working connection on the lowest level of the connection.

Having said all this, there remains the question if your router has a valid IP-address from your provider. This must be checked in the web gui of your router. Usually there is some page with status (look for the WAN connection info).

Comment: I tried the command 'ip addr' but, under the 'eth0' section, I don't have 'inet'

Comment: Could you provide the output of 'ip addr' and 'ifconfig' (please add to your Original post )

Comment: Seems you do not have an IP connection. Should have asked for another piece of info: the contents of the file /etc/network/interfaces